# Edit Parameter in JSON

Tags: json, azure

I want to deploy an Azure ARM Template.

In the parameter section I defined a IP Range for the Subnet.

```
"SubnetIP": {
  "defaultValue": "10.0.0.0",
  "type": "string"
},

"SubnetMask": {
  "type": "int",
  "defaultValue": 16,
  "allowedValues": [

    16,
    17,
    18,
    19,
    20,
    21,
    22,
    23,
    24,
    25,
    26,
    27
  ]
}
```

When creating the private IP i used

```
"privateIPAddress": "[concat(parameters('SubnetIP'),copyindex(20))]",
```

This give me not the excepted output because Subnet Ip is 10.0.0.0 and not 10.0.0.  is there a way to edit the parameter in that function?

Regards Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do a bit calculation if you want this to be robust:

```
"ipAddress32Bit": "[add(add(add(mul(int(split(parameters('ipAddress'),'.')[0]),16777216),mul(int(split(parameters('ipAddress'),'.')[1]),65536)),mul(int(split(parameters('ipAddress'),'.')[2]),256)),int(split(parameters('ipAddress'),'.')[3]))]",
"modifiedIp": "[add(variables('ipAddress32Bit'),1)]",
"ipAddressOut": "[concat(string(div(variables('modifiedIP'),16777216)), '.', string(div(mod(variables('modifiedIP'),16777216),65536)), '.', string(div(mod(variables('modifiedIP'),65536),256)), '.', string(mod(variables('modifiedIP'),256)))]"
```

not going to take credit for that. [source](https://github.com/rjmax/ArmExamples/blob/dacc551c2b089f573d8a06268d4dbda9e4031acb/networkMath.json). addition happens in the `modifiedIp` variable in this example. you could also combine this with `copy` function.

edit. ok, i thought that this is somewhat obvious, but I'll explain how I understand whats going on (i might be wrong).

1. he takes individual ip address pieces (10.1.2.3 > 10, 1, 2, 3)
2. he multiplies each piece by a specific number to get its decimal representation
3. he sums the pieces
4. he adds 1 (to get next ip address in decimal representation)
5. he casts decimal number back to ip address

To illustrate the idea use these 3 links:

https://www.browserling.com/tools/dec-to-ip
https://www.ipaddressguide.com/ip

Comment: Thank you for your help. This seems to be the best solution. It work's like a charm. Could you maybe discribe how the magic works? I wanna understand what is happening there and have absolutly no clue what concat(string(div(variables('modifiedIP'),16777216)) does.

Comment: updated my answer with explanation (i think thats what he is doing)

Answer (score 1):

So you want only the first part of the specified subnet?
maybe try something like this?

```
"variables":{
  "SubnetPrefix": "[substring(parameters('SubnetIP'), 0, lastIndexOf(parameters('SubnetIP'), '.'))]"
  "privateIPAddress": "[concat(variables('SubnetPrefix'),copyindex(20))]"

}
```

It would not be pretty for larger subnets than /24, but in the example it could work. Have a look at ARM template [string functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-string#lastindexof)